# Paginate running correctly but not passing objects to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

My paginate function is returning the documents correctly on the console but it's not properly passing them to the client. I have the paginate function set as a middleware below:

```
module.exports.paginatedResults = async (req, res, next) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {}

    if(endIndex < await Event.countDocuments().exec()) {
        results.next = {
            page: page + 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    if(startIndex > 0) {
        results.previous = {
            page: page - 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    results.results = await Event.find().limit(limit).skip(startIndex).exec()
    res.paginatedResults = results;
    console.log(results);
}
```

I then pass the results to my route handler using below:

```
const { paginatedResults } = require('../middleware');

router.route('/')
    .get(paginatedResults, catchAsync (events.index))
```

And then would like to display it on my events index page w/ below function:

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    res.render('events/index', {  paginatedResults })
};
```

When I hit the route `http://localhost:3000/events?page=3&limit=2`, the proper documents log in my terminal (because of the console.log in my paginateResults middleware function) but the browser spins and time's out.

I know my data-flow is breaking down somewhere because the `results` are not being sent to the client, but where?